# Any research paper further studying the conclusions given by Derman Regimes of Volatility

Tags: options, option-pricing, implied-volatility

As we know
Emanuel Derman mentioned 3 different market conditions where sticky delta, sticky strike, and sticky implied tree are relatively best suited.

Are there any relevant research paper further study on this topic?

Thank you

Comment: Related question https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/26435/transition-between-volatility-regimes